# Datastore export to DATASTORE_BACKUP in GCS Bucket using Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, export, google-cloud-datastore

I want to export my datastore on daily basis to GCS bucket in format DATASTORE_BACKUP. Currently I am doing Export VIA GCP Datastore Export Service with curl command as follow:

````
-X POST \
-H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/viu-data-warehouse-prod:export \
-d '{
  "labels": {
    "exportVersion": "'"$BUILD_ID"'"
  },
  "outputUrlPrefix": "'"$output_url"'",
  "entityFilter": {
    "namespaceIds": ["customer_one_view"],
    "kinds": ["user_view"]
  },
}') ```


I want it to be done by Apache Spark to make it faster. My Problem is it takes 5 to 6 hrs to finish and as Data is growing it is increasing,

I need suggestion to optimize this process by achieving Parallel processing. I would like to do it via Apache Spark as it is very Fast. Please suggest me how can I do it.
````

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't tied to Spark or the specific export format.  You could start with the Datastore to GCS Apache Beam (Dataflow) template at https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-batch#datastore-to-cloud-storage-text, then fork to to fit your needs.

Comment: Thanks @Jim Morrison for suggestions.